# PdfPTable Prefer SplitRows false

Tags: itext

Using PdfPTable with ColumnText is it possible to prefer that a row not split, but if it doesn't fit then split? Here is an example of a table with a single row and column that won't fit on a single page,

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 72f, 72f, 72f, 72f);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
            doc.Open();
            var canvas = writer.DirectContent;

            var ct = new ColumnText(canvas);

            var text = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
                text.AppendLine(i.ToString());

            // Add a table with a single row and column that doesn't fit on one page
            var t = new PdfPTable(1);
            t.SplitLate = true;
            t.SplitRows = false;
            t.WidthPercentage = 100f;

            var c = new PdfPCell();
            c.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            c.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
            c.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            c.BorderWidth = 0;
            c.Padding = 0;
            c.AddElement(new Paragraph(text.ToString()));
            t.AddCell(c);

            ct.AddElement(t);

            int status = 0;
            while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(status))
            {
                ct.SetSimpleColumn(doc.Left, doc.Bottom, doc.Right, doc.Top);
                status = ct.Go();

                if (ColumnText.HasMoreText(status))
                    doc.NewPage();
            }

            doc.Close();

            File.WriteAllBytes("d:\\test.pdf", ms.ToArray());
        }
```

I am using `SplitLate = true` and `SplitRows = false`. The call to Go() returns a status of 2 (`NO_MORE_COLUMN`) for the table.

In this example the table will span more than a page. The hope was that by using `SplitLate` and `SplitRows` I could get ColumnText to keep a row together when it could and split it when it needed to.

Is there something that I need to do with ColumnText when a status of 2 is returned so that the table will do what I'm trying to do? In this simple example I obviously know that the table doesn't fit and could set `SplitRows` to true, but in a more complex example where the data is dynamic and the size of the table or page that the table will go on is unknown (or not easily known), how can I manage to get the table to behave like this?

Comment: You do realize that `SplitRows = false` is supposed to *drop* the row if it doesn't fit, don't you? This means that data will be lost. (This is documented in the iText in Action book.) Your requirement can be met by simply setting `SplitLate` to `false`, can't it? Obviously: if a row doesn't fit a column, it will eventually have to be split.

Comment: Looks like I did have a comment in some old code indicating that SplitRows drops the row if it doesn't fit, which isn't what I want. So thanks for that reminder.

Comment: Yes, for this case `SplitLate = false` does work, but take another example of a paragraph and table where the paragraph takes up 3/4 of a page and the table takes up 1/2 of a page. I want the row to go to the next page if it doesn't fit. In that case I use `SplitLate = true` and `SplitRows = false`. That does what I want it in that case. Is there a configuration of those settings that will work for both scenarios without needing to know the size of the table ahead of time? I'd like ColumnText to prefer `SplitLate = true`, `SplitRows = false` and if it doesn't fit revert to `SplitRows = true`.

Comment: Normally, `SplitLate = true` should do the trick in that case too. It surprises me that it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like this is a difference between v4.1.6 and v5.5.6 behavior here. Under v5 the call to Go() using `SplitLate=true`, `SplitRows=false` is not dropping the row, but just continues to return status 2. Under v4 the same call to Go() will drop the row as expected. Using `SplitLate=true`, `SplitRows=true` under v4 does what I'd expect in terms of preserving the row when possible and splitting when needed, but using v5 it does not. I'm working on a conversion from v4 which is why I noticed this behavior with v5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was identified as a bug by the iText team and will be fixed in an upcoming release.